# Creating sub-tags & their classes through a given array dynamically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know that there are how many ways in JS to create sub tags and their classes names from a given array eg `array =['one','two','three','four','five']`.
If I be more specific I have already created main tags ie `<li class="card"></li>............<li class="card"></li>` of `class deck` through JS

```
`let displayCards = document.querySelector('.deck');
 for (i=0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
    let cards = document.createElement('li');
    cards.classList.add('card');
    displayCards.appendChild(cards);
 }`
```

this is the end result I want:

```
<ul class="deck">
    <li class="card">
        <i class="one"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
        <i class="two"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
        <i class="three"></i>
    </li>
</ul>
```

SO...How many ways to create sub-tags and sub-classes of all `class card` of above mentioned array.
Many Thanks

Comment: I didn't understand what is the end result you want? please provide what do you really need

Comment: this is the end result that I want. Thanks
`<ul class="deck">
            <li class="card">
                <i class="one"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="two"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="three"></i>
            </li>
.....................
/ul>`

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay, I just posted my answer, have a look and let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi Zeeshan...I will check it later on.....Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can do it's just like what you tried already.

Html:

```
 <ul class="deck">
 </ul>
```

JS:

```
             <script>
              $(document).ready(function () {
                    var symbols = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
                    let displayCards = document.querySelector('.deck');
                    for (i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
                          let cards = document.createElement('li');
                          cards.classList.add('card');
                          let childCard = document.createElement('i');
                          childCard.classList.add(symbols[i]);
                          childCard.innerHTML += symbols[i];
                          cards.appendChild(childCard);
                          displayCards.appendChild(cards);
                    }
              });

        </script>
```